# Not abstract and does not override abstract method createViewManagers

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a bridge for react-native based application and package below is eroring with

> error: RNGoogleSignInPackage is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext) in
>   ReactPackage

```
package com.asimetriq.rngooglesignin;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RNGoogleSignInPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new RNGoogleSignInModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell I am missing implementation for `createViewManagers` but I don't see where it's supposed to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implemented ReactPackage and you need to override **createNativeModules** and **createViewManagers**. So you should add that.

```
     @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
         // return your view manager list at here...
        );
}
```

Comment: I see, is there a common practice to return null / empty view managers? I don't have any. i.e can I return an empty list?

Comment: add this : return Collections.emptyList();  and pls add this:  import java.util.Collections;